# Change ID to Customer name

Tags: javascript, pdf, netsuite, suitescript

I Rename at PDF netsuite with Suitelet method

```
var paramGet = context.request.parameters;
var customer = paramGet.salesname;
var location = paramGet.location;
var startDate = paramGet.startdate;
var endDate = paramGet.enddate;
var number = paramGet.number;
var flagExport = paramGet.flag
var trans = getSales(customer, startDate, endDate, number);


var rawPdfData = getDataSet('pdfdata', trans, checkedValue, number)
    log.debug('raw pdf data', rawPdfData)
    var dataZip = []
    for (x = 0; x < rawPdfData.length; x++) {
        var dataPdf = JSON.stringify(rawPdfData[x])
        log.debug("log data pdf", dataPdf)
        var renderer = render.create();
        log.debug("renderer", renderer)
        renderer.setTemplateByScriptId('CUSTTMPL_160_7537160_SB1_255');
        renderer.addCustomDataSource({
            alias: "record",
            format: render.DataSource.JSON,
            data: dataPdf
        })
        var tempelatePdf = renderer.renderAsPdf();
        tempelatePdf.name = ""+ number +"" + customer +"[" + x + "] KODECUSTOMER .pdf"
        dataZip.push(tempelatePdf)

    }
```

But the result output at the customer has ID not a customer name

[image]

can I change ID to the customer name? Thanks for helping

Comment: what `log.debug("log data pdf", dataPdf)` log prints?

Comment: @RavikumarRajendran this result print  export pdf    `{"name": "PT.CARGILL INDONESIA",
    "address": "JL.MANYAR KM 25 BETA PLOT 2 KIM RT.000 RW.000 MANYAR SIDOMUKTI - MANYAR GRESIK",
    "npwp": "01.002.071,7-057.000",
    "noAts": "",
    "nomorPemb": "20220810001",`}

Comment: try `rawPdfData[x].name` instead of  `customer`, Hope it will help!